# Unable to get the property or its methods in Symfony2

Tags: php, symfony

So my problem is that whenever I try to submit a form I get error like this.I am trying to save data in the database.

```
Neither the property "catalogId" nor one of the methods "addCatalogId()"/"removeCatalogId()", "setCatalogId()", "catalogId()", "__set()" or "__call()" exist and have public access in class "RetailMapping\Bundle\RetailOutletBundle\Entity\RetailOutlet"
```

But I do have catalogId and its getters and setters.But when I use public $catalogId instead of private $catalogId it works. This is my retailoutlet.php entity. I am assuming that the problem is originating from here(I have removed some of the codes that is not relevant).

```
namespace RetailMapping\Bundle\RetailOutletBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;

/**
 * RetailOutlet.
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="retail_outlet")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="RetailMapping\Bundle\RetailOutletBundle\Entity\RetailOutletRepository")
 */
class RetailOutlet
{
    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;


    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="RetailMapping\Bundle\CatalogBundle\Entity\Catalog")
     * @ORM\JoinTable(name="retailshop_inventory",
     *     joinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="retail_outlet_id", referencedColumnName="id")},
     *     inverseJoinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="catalog_id", referencedColumnName="id")}
     * )
     */
    private $catalogId;

    /**
     * Get id.
     *
     * @return integer
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * Constructor.
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->retailOutletId = new ArrayCollection();
    }

    /**
     * Add retailOutletId.
     *
     * @param \RetailMapping\Bundle\RetailOutletBundle\Entity\RetailOutlet $retailOutletId
     *
     * @return RetailOutlet
     */
    public function addRetailOutletId(\RetailMapping\Bundle\RetailOutletBundle\Entity\RetailOutlet $retailOutletId)
    {
        $this->retailOutletId[] = $retailOutletId;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Remove retailOutletId.
     *
     * @param \RetailMapping\Bundle\RetailOutletBundle\Entity\RetailOutlet $retailOutletId
     */
    public function removeRetailOutletId(\RetailMapping\Bundle\RetailOutletBundle\Entity\RetailOutlet $retailOutletId)
    {
        $this->retailOutletId->removeElement($retailOutletId);
    }

    /**
     * Get retailOutletId.
     *
     * @return \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection
     */
    public function getRetailOutletId()
    {
        return $this->retailOutletId;
    }

    /**
     * Add catalogId.
     *
     * @param \RetailMapping\Bundle\CatalogBundle\Entity\Catalog $catalogId
     *
     * @return RetailOutlet
     */
    public function addCatalogId(\RetailMapping\Bundle\CatalogBundle\Entity\Catalog $catalogId)
    {
        $this->catalogId[] = $catalogId;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Remove catalogId.
     *
     * @param \RetailMapping\Bundle\CatalogBundle\Entity\Catalog $catalogId
     */
    public function removeCatalogId(\RetailMapping\Bundle\CatalogBundle\Entity\Catalog $catalogId)
    {
        $this->catalogId->removeElement($catalogId);
    }

    /**
     * Get catalogId.
     *
     * @return \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection
     */
    public function getCatalogId()
    {
        return $this->catalogId;
    }
}
```

And this is my form. It is perfectly showing the data from the database in the dropdown.

```
<div class="form-group">
            <label for="retailmapping_bundle_retailoutletbundle_retailoutlet_catalogid"> Catalog Id </label>
            {{ form_widget(form.catalogId, {'attr':{'class':'form-control'}})}}
        </div>
```

Comment: Have you code the setter and getter of catalogId in your class ?

Comment: @YenneInfo yes i have

Comment: Can you share the class where you code the setter/getter.... (get set add and remove CatalogId)

Comment: @YenneInfo do u know what is wrong here?

Comment: The problem is solved. Took me 2 days.